Are there any active reviewers or moderators on this site?
A week ago I suggested an excerpt for the returns wiki excerpt.  As of this writing it has not been approved.
Are all reviewers and moderators MIA?

Nope we're alive and kicking and quite active. I'm afraid I can't remember your edit. I see three obvious possibilities for bona fide edits not being approved:

We didn't accept it
We didn't see it then for some reason 
Something else went wrong. 

P.S. Your edit for sharpe-ratio is approved and much appreciated.

I don't see any flags for you; which question did you flag?

I can't find it either.  Maybe the system deletes them after a week?  I didn't have enough rep to even contact anyone on this site until today.

BTW, this isn't a very good answer, but I can't downvote it, and given the level of voting on QF I don't think I'm likely to ever get rep from Q&A, so lucky you ;)

Oh: just checked my profile and realized it was for tag wiki content.  Question updated.
